# Discrete Mathematics - Any Proof Accepted

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am given:

for all integers *a* and *b*, if *a* is even and *b* is a multiple of $3$, then *a**b* is a multiple of $6$.

I started the problem with

Since *a* is even, then $a=2k$
Since *b* is a multiple of $3$; then $b=3k$

So

$ab = (2k)(3k) = 6k^2$

Right? Is another direct proof? I can choose between any of the following proofs

Direct Proof

Proof by Contrapostive

Proof by Contradiction

Proof by Counter-Example

Proof by Cases

Comment: Why would $a$ and $b$ both be multiples of the same $k$? You have the right idea, but your notation is a little off.

Comment: "Since a is even, then a=2k"  Not if a = 54 and k=13.  But whatever $a$ is it is $2*k$ for *some*$k$.  "Since b is a multiple of 3; then b=3k" ditto.  "$ab=(2k)(3k)=6k^2$. Right?" Absolutely wrong.  Let $a = 14 = 2*7=2*k$ and $b = 15=3*5= 3*k$.  So $ab = 14*15 =210= 6*35 = 6*k^2$.  So $35= k^2$ but $35$ isn't a square.  Do you see what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite right. $a=2k$ and $b=3l$, but there is no restriction that $k=l$.

$$ab=(2k)(3l)=6(kl)$$

Since $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$, $kl \in \mathbb{Z}$, and hence $ab$ is a multiple of $6$.

Comment: And this is a direct proof. The converse of course is not true...right?

Comment: $6=6(1).$ $1$ is not a multiple of $2$ and $1$ is not a multiple of $3$.

Comment: That's pretty straightforward. I am just hesitant is suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Direct proof:

If $a$ is even then $a = 2k$ for *some* integer $k$. and if $b$ is a multiple of $3$ then $b = 3j$ for *some* $j$  which may or may not be a different integer that the integer $k$.

Then $ab = 2k*3j = 6kj$.  As $kj$ is an integer, $6kj$ is a multiple of $6$.

QED.

Proof by Contradict.

Let $a = 2k$ be an even number for *some* integer $k$ and let $b = 3j$ be a multiple of $3$ for some $j$.

Assume $ab$ is not a multiple of $6$.  Then $ab$ will have a remainder $r$ when divided by $6$.  That is $ab = 6m + r$ for some integer $m$ and some integer $r$ where $1 \le r < 6$.

So $ab = 2k3j = 6kj = 6m + r$.

So $r = 6kj - 6m$

$r = 6(kj - m)$.  So $r$ is a multiple of $6$.  But that contradicts that $1 \le r < 5$.

So it is not possible that $ab$ is *not* a multiple of $6$.  So $ab$ must be a multiple of $6$.

That was a proof by contradiction.

As you can see that really was a very inefficient proof.

Proof by contrapositive:

That would be to assume $ab$ is not a multiple of $6$.  Then prove that that would mean that it can not be that both $a$ is even and $b$ is a multiple of $3$.

This would be *very* inefficient.  If we assume that $ab$ have a non-zerro remainder when divided by $6$,  we can prove that either $a$ will have a remainder of $1$ when divided by $2$ or that $b$ will have a reamainder of $1$ or $2$ when divided by $3$.

However the prof is *so* tedious and round about, I think I would just confuse things if I brought it up.

Proof by counter example:

A proof by counter example can only prove that something is *not* true.

If I could find an even number $a$ such as $a = 2,146$ and a multiple of $3$ such as $b = 369$ where $ab = 791,875$ is not a multiple of $6$ then that would prove the statement is not true.

However the statement *is* true and I can *not* find any such counter-example because no such counter-example exists.

Proof by Cases:

This is not really appropriate.

Let $a = 2k$ be even for some $k$. and Let $b= 3j$ by a multiple of $3$ for some $j$.

Case 1:

$j$ is even.  Then $j = 2m$ for some $m$.  Then $b=3*2m = 6m$.  And $ab = 6am$ is a multiple of $6$.

Case 2:

$j$ is odd.  Then $j = 2m + 1$ for some $m$. So $b = 3(2m+ 1) = 6m + 3$.  So $ab = a(6m +3) = 6am + 3a = 6am + 3(2k) = 6am + 6k = 6(am + k)$ which is a multiple of $6$.

Those are all possible cases and in all of them it turns out $ab$ is a multiple of $6$.  So $ab$ is always a multiple of $6$ if $a$ is even or $b $ is a multiple of $3$.

====

ALl in all, a direct proof is best for this statement.